# Increment total by one when cell value changes

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I thought this was simple but I'm stumped: I have three columns, User Name, Hit counter, and Total Hits. Hit counter will have either a 0 or a 1 while Total Hits will count the total number of times column Hit Counter ever contains a 1.

The idea is if someone changes a 0 to a 1, then the adjacent cell in B should increase by 1. There is no change if someone changes that 1 back to a 0, but if someone else comes in and changes 0 back to 1, then total should continue to increase by one.

| Hit Count | Hit counter | Total hits |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Test1 | 0 | 1 |
| Test2 | 1 | 3 |

In the above table, if someone changes Test1 hit counter to 1, then Total hits should go up to 2. If someone changes that to 0 and then 1 again, it should go up to 3.

Is there a way to do this with formula's and not Apps Script or code? If not, how would I do this in code or Apps Script?

Thanks!!

Comment: If you are using Google sheets and not Excel, please modify those tags too.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of an Excel formula is to take the values as they are currently on the sheet and perform a calculation. Identical values will lead to identical formula outcomes.

You are looking for a way to have different values, even when the values are equal, e.g.

You start with situation:

```
0   1(calculated)
1   3(calculated)
```

The upper left value changes to 1 and back to 0, and the situation would become:

```
0   2(calculated)
1   3(calculated)
```

This means: different values, based on identical values, which is not feasible using only formulas.

However, using VBA, based on events like `Worksheet_Change()` or `Worksheet_SelectionChange()`, this is possible.

Comment: How would I do this in app script?

Comment: The mentioned `Worksheet_Change()` and `Worksheet_SelectionChange()` events have a `Target` parameter. You check that one (both column reference and value) and based on that, you modify value next to it using the `Offset()`.